# Cloud security and privacy

Tags: security, cloud

I have a very basic doubt regarding cloud computing that is catching up pretty fast these days. To my understanding, cloud computing is a paradigm in which companies put up their data and applications on somebody else's machines aka 'The Cloud'. I want to know just how secure is it to put up my data on some third party machines, especially if my data contains private details. In particular, how can an enterprise trust the cloud computing service providers in this data privacy aspect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what kind of data you want to store.

If you are speaking of credit card or financial information, then its *NOT* secure. PCI Level 1 compliance rules out any possibility of using the cloud, because to be compliant you need to perform third party *on-site* audits, and most cloud providers don't allow that. Here is [Amazon's stand on](http://www.mckeay.net/2009/08/14/cannot-achieve-pci-compliance-with-amazon-ec2s3/) it. For any other data that requires legal compliance, you will find it difficult to host it on the cloud.

For other kinds of data that doesn't need legal compliance, it all boils down to your enterprise's risk appetite and the kind of cloud vendor you are dealing with. Completely agree with Stephen on this.

For general information on cloud security, you should visit [Cloud Security Alliance](http://cloudsecurityalliance.org/). They have the most relevant information in this field.

Answer (score 1):

If you're that worried about security, perhaps you should be looking elsewhere other than the cloud and instead at a trusted provider or running your own.

Comment: I wish I had considered this before implementing my REST service on the cloud

Comment: These days, there's decent support for PCI on Amazon. All is not lost. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the CSA (cloud security association) 75% of cloud services are not secure, from privacy and data security perspective there is zero methods or enforcement of basic security.
From my own self-experience, SAAS apps creators think about security only in two case: 1. The company is mature and funded 2.They got hacked.

Enterprise should ask each vendor about their security whitepaper/certifications in the relevant area like PCI DSS, HIPAA, SOX etc...

Answer (score 0):

> In particular, how can an enterprise trust the cloud computing service providers in this data privacy aspect?

Good question.

I guess, it boils down to carefully examining the fine print of a cloud computing service provider, seeing what they guarantee about privacy (and whether those guarantees have legal backing) and then making a "business decision" that weighs the risks and benefits.

Generally speaking, developers should not be making these decisions.

Comment: well, the point is that the damage would have been done if the data privacy is compromised, right?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I there is no "damage" in compromising data privacy, then the whole question of data privacy is moot ... from the enterprise perspective.